# How to limit access to various services per user using Django-mama-CAS?

Tags: python, django, cas

I am using `django-mama-cas` module to implement Single Sign On for third-party apps. Is there a way to limit access to different services for each user  ?

I know there is an option in the settings : `MAMA_CAS_VALID_SERVICES` to limit valid URLs but what I am interested in limiting access to some of these services per user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to implement a [custom callback](http://django-mama-cas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#django.conf.settings.MAMA_CAS_ATTRIBUTE_CALLBACKS). The callback is passed both the user object and the service URL, so you can limit access based on whatever combinations are required. If the test fails, raise PermissionDenied to abort the request (the same thing that is done if an invalid service is provided). If you do not require any custom attributes, simply return an empty dictionary on success.